# How do I bundle an exe with OpenCandy's offer platform?

Tags: api, executable

I have an existing exe file which I would love to have launched from a new installer using the OpenCandy platform.

See here: http://www.opencandy.com/developers/signup/ for OC's integration options. Maybe it could be in the form of a downloader? Or maybe it could just be a fairly empty installer that has OC's api integrated and then will open an embedded exe (all I have is the exe).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can download our SDK at http://media.opencandy.com/sdk/OpenCandyPublisherKit.zip, which includes instructions for integrating OpenCandy. If you have any questions, there's also a contact address in there.Basically you create an installer (like NSIS or Inno) to install your app/exe and integrate OpenCandy into it.

Be well and good luck integrating!

Dr. Apps

Software Community Guru

OpenCandy